# Change order of visible items

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Is it possible to move up/down the visual items in order to change its overlapping?  currently, the child hides its parent, but i'd like to have the reverse, i.e. the parent hides the child. Maybe some properties exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You will need to change the `z` property of the involved items. According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop):

> Sets the stacking order of sibling items. By default the stacking order is 0.
>
> Items with a higher stacking value are drawn on top of siblings with a lower stacking order. Items with the same stacking value are drawn bottom up in the order they appear. **Items with a negative stacking value are drawn under their parent's content**.

Hence, you only need to set `z` property of children to a negative value:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Rectangle {
    width:800
    height: 480
    color: "yellow"
    // opacity: 0.5   (1)
    Rectangle{
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color:"red"
        z:-1
    }
}
```

In this example the inner `Rectangle` is *not visible* since its `z` property has a negative value. Uncomment the `opacity` assignament of the outer `Rectangle` in (1) to see it.

Comment: Pay attention: `z` defines stacking order of [sibling items only](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop) But `Items with a negative stacking value are drawn under their parent's content`

Comment: @ folibis Items with a higher stacking value are drawn on top of siblings with a lower stacking order. Items with the same stacking value are drawn bottom up in the order they appear. Items with a negative stacking value are drawn under their parent's content.Higher z on top... http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prophttp://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop  It's the z order see documentation, it is what his looking for :)

Comment: @folibis was pointing that while your code answers the question the text is not interely correct. Add the sentence he proposed.

Comment: @BaCARoZzo ah ok, I didn't understand hes  comment , done:)

Comment: thanks! Is it possible, when visual items aren't siblings and not parent-child relationship? I.e. child of one visual item should hide sibling of its parent.

Comment: @john Kush yes it's possible ,z is a real it takes  not only  0, 1 or -1, you can always increase the z in order to hide a parent of a parent.   if you want some object to be always on top per example put it's z : Infinity, ...