# How to draw a QQuickItem on a QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have two `QQuickItem`s and I would like to draw one on top of the other in C++ before it is exposed to QML. I would like to do this because I want the second `QQuickItem` (which I would refer to as background `QQuickItem` from here on) to act as the background of the first `QQuickItem` (which I would refer to as parent `QQuickItem` from here on) and then draw a `QPixmap` (which has been painted on using `QPainter`) on top of both items. I would also prefer to pass in the second "background" `QQuickItem` as a property to the first `QQuickItem` so that it can be set dynamically from QML. Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

I would like to mention that both `QQuickItem`s have implementations of `QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()`. Is there a way to make them work together?

Comment: It seems to be Z order problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527916/change-order-of-visible-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you have to use the visual [`parent` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#parent-prop) (note that in c++ you access it with `setParentItem()` and `parentItem()`, not `parent()` which is  for the `QObject` parent).

If you want to have a background property, I guess you don't want to have your background as the parent of your item, so you could instead set yourself as the parent of the background and set the background's `z` to -1 so it paints behind your item.

Alternatively, and that's what Qt Quick Controls 2 do, you could have a `QQuickItem` painting nothing and just be a parent for your background and your content item (QQC2 controls expose their `contentItem` as a property but you don't have to).
For some inspiration you can check the source code of QQC2's [`Control`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html) here : https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtquickcontrols2/src/quicktemplates2/qquickcontrol.cpp.html

Don't forget to handle the resizing of your background to the size of your item.